# Explicitly computing Donaldson-Thomas invariants (of CY 3-folds)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, gromov-witten-theory, calabi-yau, enumerative-geometry

I am interested in the explicit computation of generating functions of rank 1 and higher rank Donaldson-Thomas (DT) invariants. In particular, I am interested in DT invariants of K3 fibered Calabi-Yau threefolds, and their modularity. Given a specific CY 3-fold and a fixed K3 lattice polarization, how can one systematically compute the DT invariants. What data of the CY 3-fold do I need? I am interested in not just smooth CYs, but smooth ones is a natural starting point, and I don't know how to handle those.

Are there any references, where such computations have been worked out, maybe in very simple cases.

Answer (score 3):

This answer might just be a list of references, but I hope it helps. The most explicit computations of which I am aware exploit a torus action on the Calabi-Yau 3-fold in question, where the calculus can be reduced to a combinatorial problem: for example, the famous paper [Gromov–Witten theory and Donaldson–Thomas theory. I](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X06002302) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2264664)) by Maulik, Nekrasov, Okounkov, and Pandharipande. The same approach yields explicit computations for stable pairs invariants, as done by Pandharipande and Thomas in another paper, [The 3-fold vertex via stable pairs](https://msp.org/gt/2009/13-4/p01.xhtml). Finally, one more case where it might be possible to compute Donaldson-Thomas invariants is when you can describe the corresponding moduli space as a critical locus, and compute the perverse sheaf of vanishing cycles, as done by Dimca and Szendrői in [The Milnor fibre of the Pfaffian and the Hilbert scheme of four points on $\mathbb C^3$](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/mrl/content/vols/0016/0006/a012/). Joyce and Song have greatly developed the theory of invariants for local vanishing loci, but it might not be a good place to start to look for explicit computations.

Comment: When you link to MSN, you need to click the "Make Link" button on the specific review you want.  This allows even non-subscribed users to see the article to which you're pointing.  If instead you use the auto-generated link (which records the search you got there), then non-subscribed users cannot see it at all.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. I will make sure my links to MSN are available to non-subscribers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think an important reference for your question is Maulik and Pandharipande's paper on Noether-Lefschetz theory: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.1653.pdf

Their results are phrased in terms of Gromov-Witten theory, but the same result applies to Donaldson-Thomas theory. In particular, they tell you how to compute the DT/GW partition function for curve classes in the fiber of a $K3$ fibered Calabi-Yau threefold. The answer involves the partition function for local $K3$ surfaces along with the "Noether-Lefschetz" number of the family of $K3$s defined by the fibration, i.e. the number of times the base of the family hits the Noether-Lefschetz divisor (associated to the fiber curve class) in the moduli space of $K3$ surfaces. The generating function for both the NL numbers and the local $K3$ invariants have modular properties which are explained in that paper.